# Play application.conf : Where to consult the list of all possible variable?

Tags: playframework-2.3

Where can i find the list of all possible variable that is possible to set in play application.conf ?

I can't find this information on playframework website.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use IDE such as `eclipse` or `IntelliJ`, you can inspect `Play.application().configuration()` at runtime while debugging and it will contain all possble configuration key/value pairs. It briefly looks as follows:

```
{
   "akka":{ },
   "application":{ },
   "applyEvolutions":{ },
   "awt":{ },
   "db":{ },
   "dbplugin":"disabled",
   "evolutionplugin":"enabled",
   "file":{ },
   "java":{ },
   "jline":{ },
   "line":{ },
   "logger":{ },
   "os":{ },
   "path":{ },
   "play":{ },
   "promise":{ },
   "report":{ },
   "sbt":{ },
   "sun":{ },
   "user":{ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such list of all possible variables, since the `application.conf` is arbitrarily extensible by all sorts of tools and components, most of them third party, and can contain any config the user wants.

For example: the configuration detailing Play's [thread pools](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools#Configuring-the-default-thread-pool) is really just [Akka](http://akka.io/) configuration.

The key things (DB config, languages, evolutions) are in the template, either with default values or commented out, when you initialise a new Play application.

The [config](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration) page on the site discusses some additional configuration you might need, but this mostly relates to concerns *external* to the application, like launching and logging.

Comment: Ok i understand but is there a way i can list all the properties of the session object ? Thanx

Comment: @MartinH-Works ah, then see the other answer ;)